# two-way ANOVA output - summary or apa.aov.table?

Tags: anova, summary

If I calculate a two-way ANOVA with the code "aov", what should I use to interpret the data, the "summary" of the ANOVA shown in the console or the apa.aov.table which produces a APA style table in word? The p-Values differ a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the reason why the p values differs is that the aov() function defaults to type I sums of squares. However, the apa.aov.table() function defaults to type III sums of squares, unless specified otherwise (documentation here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/apaTables/versions/2.0.8/topics/apa.aov.table).

At least in my area, type III sums of squares is kind of the standard at the moment, so if that is also the case for you, I would recommend the Anova() function from the "Car" package, which allows you to specify which type you would like to use.